# how would I find the min value of an index AFTER a certain value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following list as such:

```
y  =  np.array([    9.7,   10.1,   10.5,  10.2,  10.1,  9.9,   9.8])
```

I want to find the index of a minimum value that fulfils the criteria of having passed both a threshold and the max of said threshold.

In this, instance the threshold is 10. Hence, I would want a value that has surpassed 10 as well as the max value past threshold, 10.5. The minimum I want would be 10.1. This is my code.

```
max_height = np.max(py)
height_alien = 10
x = np.where(np.logical_and(py < max_height, py >= height_alien))
```

I know it's wrong because I am not specifically stating that I want indexes after the max. How would I do that? I keep getting x = (array[1,3,4])
My intended answers would be (array[3,4]) upon which I would get index 4.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just ditch the first index? `x[0][1:]` will give you all the indices where the condition holds after the first one

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new array starting from the given index and then do `np.max(newArray)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want your where condition to only consider values starting after some other condition.

```
y = np.array([9.7,   10.1,   10.5,  10.2,  10.1,  9.9,   9.8])

max_height = np.argmax(y)
height_alien = 10
x = np.where(np.logical_and(np.arange(0,y.size) > max_height, y >= height_alien))
```

I used `argmax` to find the index of the maximum value and used `arange` to create an index array of the form `[0 1 2 3 ...]`. This array is compared to the argmax of y, resulting in an boolean array of the form `[False False ... True True ...]`.